# Playing back multiple sounds simultaneously and precisely with Audio Queue?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, playback, audioqueue

I need to have a series of sound samples (audio files) being played back at the touch of a button. The audio samples need to be played back simultaneously and precisely (think 4 voices in a piece of music).

I managed to do this with several instances of AVAudioPlayer but it will go out of sync.
Reading about it, due to lack of precision it seems to not be the right choice for I'm trying to do.

Audio queue (is this part of Core Audio?) seems to be able to do what I want but I can hardly find any code bits in Swift to setup what I’m trying to do, which is:

Load the audio file, prepare it to be played, then play it (I would trigger it with an NSTimer).

Is this straightforward to implement with audio queue or should I look elsewhere?
If you could point me into the right direction I would be very grateful.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am unsure about Audio Queue, however, I have used `AVPlayer` extensively and have found it to be very accurate. I have not used it to play multiple sounds at once but I believe you could do so with multiple instances similar to your `AVAudioPlayer` example, only it would be more precise. Using `AVQueuePlayer` (a subclass of `AVPlayer`) you can preload your media files so they are ready for immediate playback at the touch of a button. Or you can use `AVAsset` to preload your asset and play it with `AVPlayer`

Comment: Thans for your answer, but as I said, AVPlayer is ok for playing a button sound here and there but it will not be precise enough, once a few instances play simultaneously. The timing will be all over the place. That's why I need to look elsewhere.

Comment: In your question you mention `AVAudioPlayer` but you never mention `AVPlayer` , perhaps you are unaware that they are two different media players

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your comment, I didn't know these were different players. However, I've tried `AVPlayer` now, too, and unfortunately, it's even worse than `AVAudioPlayer`. The timing is off. It may not be noticeable when playing single sounds when touching a button but when there's a melody consisting of different audio samples it's really obvious. Also, it skips sounds here and there, in the simulator and on the device. With `AVAudioPlayer` this happened only in the simulator. It seems I need to get into AudioQueue.

Comment: Thats strange, I use `AVPlayer` in an application requiring a high degree of precision and i've found it to meet my requirements. `AVQueuePlayer` allows for preloading of assets, perhaps that may help you. If you would post your code that would help

Comment: Hello Nontomatic, did you ever find the solution to your problem? I happen to be facing a very similar situation.

Comment: Hi, yes, I eventually found a way to do this with perfect precision for multiple sounds. It was even possible with AVAudioPlayer, so I didn't end up using AudioQueue. In my case the app was playing back notes it read from a given score, so if you're planning to trigger sounds while playing yourself without any latency this won't be for you. I used the Timer(fireAt: ...) method and the trick was to subtract the time it took to setup and prepare the AVAudioPlayer for each of the sounds from the initial fire date. Let me know whether that helps.